# Pointer to Value of another pointer in C (Embedded)

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, null-pointer

In this code: Pointer_pu32 points to variable a, but which is pointer Boot_st point to?

```
 int * Boot_st;
 int a = 15;
 int * Pointer_pu32 = &a;
 Boot_st = (int *)(*Pointer_pu32); /* what was this code line mean? */
```

When I try to run

```
printf("Address of A : %ld\n", &a);
printf("Boot_st : %ld\n", Boot_st);
printf("Address Boot_st : %ld\n", &Boot_st);
printf("Pointer_pu32 : %ld\n", Pointer_pu32);
```

Here is the result:

```
Address of A: 3996460
Boot_st : 15
Address Boot_st : 3996472
Pointer_pu32 : 3996460
```

That means: `Boot_st` contains the value of `a`, could you explain the behavior of the pointer `Boot_st` and `Pointer_pu32`?

Comment: Also note that the `%ld` format expects a value of the type `long int`. And that (`void *`, cast is needed) pointers should be printed by the `%p` format. Mismatching `printf` format specifier and value type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `Boot_st = (int *)(*Pointer_pu32);` is synonymous with `Boot_st = a;`, which is assigning an `int` to an `int*` and therefore nonsense.  Besides using the wrong format specifier for printing pointers (as pointed out, should be `%p`), printing `&Boot_st` is worthless. Its address means nothing relevant to the code in question. The address it *holds* is relevant, but only in so far as it exercised an improper assignment from `int` in the first place. And none of these has *anything* to do with either the `embedded` or `null-pointer` tags, which consequently should not even be here.

Comment: Hi WhozCraig ,
In case : uint32 * Pointer_pu32 = (uint32*) 0x00002004 (manually assigned) and Boot_st = (uint32 *)(*Pointer_pu32) .That mean Boot_st contain value in address 0x00002004 ,right? .Boot_st is another pointer type uint32  in this case

Answer (score 3):

This code line `Boot_st = (int *)(*Pointer_pu32);` means

- take this pointer to an integer `Pointer_pu32`
- dereference it `(*Pointer_pu32)` to read the integer value
- cast it, to consider that value as a pointer to an integer `(int *)`
- write that to a variable of type "pointer to an integer" `Boot_st =`

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch , in caseuint32 * Pointer_pu32 = (uint32*) 0x00002004 (manually assigned) and Boot_st = (uint32 *)(*Pointer_pu32).That mean Boot_st contain value in address 0x00002004 ,right? with (uint32 *Boot_st)

Comment: Yes. This is a pattern often used in the context of memory mapped peripherals. Be careful with the data type sizes.